# How do you do a melee attack in Just Cause 2?

Tags: just-cause-2

There's achievements and all kinds of moaning about it on forums, but no-one actually says how you do the darn action itself.

Is there a bizarre key combination to press? Do you need a melee weapon? Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The  <kbd>Q</kbd> key is the default key used to perform a melee attack. It is not performed with a melee weapon; it's actually an extension of your grappling hook. There is no such thing as a melee weapon.

If you're playing on an Xbox 360, the 'B' button performs a melee attack.